# Using a capacitor as a battery?

Tags: capacitor

I have a 95microF +5% 250v.ac c 50/60 capacitor. And I would like to use it as a  battery even if it only last a couple hours. I have a charger I made for it but the cap. Drains way to fast. I was thinking about using a dimmer switch to reduce it. Or maybe even some resistors to reduce the output voltage to like 10v roughly. I was planning on heating up nichrome wire (68ohm resistance) with this cap. So I can heat the wire up without damaging my power source.

Comment: "reduce the current to 10v" makes no sense. Current is measured in amps, not volts.

Comment: And you won't get it to last seconds doing the job of a battery, let alone hours.

Comment: Impossible to answer unless we know what you're trying to power.

Comment: Trying to heat up wire for now...I believe the wire is 68ohm resistance.. Sorry I was multi tasking and put current for volts

Comment: Please edit your question to correct any mistakes you made and to clarify about the load you're trying to provide power to.

Comment: Good luck getting it to last even a few seconds

Comment: Charles is helping me out good

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because The poster has no concept of what they are attempting, and seem (from the comments) to be attempting potentially dangerous experiments with no actual knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a 250 V, AC capacitor can be charged to 350 V, DC. That would give you 0.5 X 95 X 10^-6 X 350^2 = 5.8 Joules or 5.8 watt-seconds. If you can recover 75% of that you would have 4.4 watt-seconds. If you use that over two hours, you would have 4.4 / 7200 = 0.6 milliwatts.

Comment: 350 v is a lot I'll have to rethink my idea...would I super capacitor work ok with heating up 2-6in nichrom wire 68ohm resistance? Or is lithium ion best?

Comment: And no I wasn't going to use the 250v capacitor to heat up the small amount of wire.

Comment: Charles . when u said if I use it for over 2hours what r u figuring when it comes to what I'm using it on?

Comment: What Charles is saying is that it would provide \$\frac {1}{10,000}\$ of the power required to power a 6 W car tail lamp for two hours. i.e. Almost nothing. Charles has told you that your capacitor can store 4.4 watt-seconds. You need to figure out how many watts your heater requires, divide that into 4.4 and that will tell you how many seconds it will last. e.g., If you require 20 W to power your heater then it will last \$\frac{4.4}{20} = 0.22 s\$.

Comment: 350 volts is the peak voltage for 250 V, AC.  That is probably the DC rating of your capacitor. You can put a different in the formula Energy = 1/2 X C X V-squared. Unless you are trying to demonstrate something about capacitors, it would be better to connect the wire to a 9-volt battery. That would give you about 1 watt. It won't make the wire super hot, but you should be able to tell that it is being heated.

Comment: Ok so I can connect it to a 9v. Is it true that if I take 2 9v and connect them in series that the current will b the same. There fore the wire won't get any hotter but a longer portion of it will heat up?

Comment: And if that's true then can a run a wire off each positive then connect a diode to each lead, then connect both wires past the diodes, then connect the single hot to the wire. But when I get past the wire fork off to the negatives to complete the circuit. Would that raise the volts and current?

Comment: Double voltage and double wire length twice the power distributed in twice the wire length, so the temperature will be about the same. I don't have time to figure out what you mean about the rest. Draw the circuit and ask a new question. Perhaps someone else can help.

Answer (score 3):

TWO HOURS?  Your capacitor cannot store the amount energy that's required to heat up nichrome wire for even one minute.   Well, it might work for a second or so.   That's why we use batteries instead of capacitors.

At 250V, a 95uF capacitor stores about three joules of energy.    Compare this to a single triple-A battery which stores about 1000 joules of energy.  Three joules?  That can run a three-watt heater for only one second.

See the problem?  Capacitors can't provide heating unless they're really huge.

How long is your nichrome?  If it's not tiny, then to heat it significantly you probably want five or ten watts of energy flow.

Try using a 9v power supply to heat up 68ohms nichrome wire.  That gives 1.2W heating at 130mA current.  Barely warm.   If you want to burn your fingers, try using 24V power supply on your same wire.

Yes, supercapacitors would work, but their voltage is a bit too low to use with 68 ohms.  A large supercapacitor the size of a soup can stores about the same energy as one alkaline C-cell.   The usual supercapacitor trick is to short the capacitor with extremely thin copper or steel wire.  The wire resistance is a fraction of one ohm.  The wire gets very hot, very quickly, and can even glow red.

Comment: Ok so my nicromide wire is 40 gauge and I already know I need 12v 1200mA will heat up 6in. Of the wire before its not red. Can I just divide the volts and MA by how ever much I'm shortening the wire?  Example: 6v 600mah will heat up 3 inches to the point its barely red

Comment: 12V X 1200mA = 14.4 Joules / second. Your capacitor holds 3 Joules. You can't even heat it for one second with your capacitor.

Comment: @user100476  your capacitor holds hundreds of times *less* energy than even a tiny battery.    To heat your wire for many seconds, your capacitor needs to be larger than a basketball.   Get a capacitor the size of a small car, and you can heat the wire for a couple of hours.  Or just use batteries instead.   But yes, for nichrome you can keep the current the same but divide the volts.   Six inches at 12V will heat the wire to the same temperature as three inches powered by 6V.  But both need the same high current.  The current doesn't divide.

Comment: Ok thanks....does that watts come in the picture when working with this? Ive heard it has but also Hurd it doesn't matter.

Comment: @user100476 the watts is telling you the heating rate.   If you keep the current in your nichrome wire always the same, then a longer wire gives more total heat, and needs more total watts.   Double the length of the wire, and you need double the volts and double the watts, while keeping current the same.   Then each cm of wire will stay at about the same temperature, even though voltage and wattage is much higher.  It's the same as hooking more and more resistors in series, and then increasing the supply voltage so each resistor still gets hot.  The long chain of resistors needs higher watts.

Answer (score 1):

As capacitor is 95microF +5% 250v.ac 50/60Hz.

Energy of capacitor = C * V^2 / 2

Q= 0.000095*240^2 = 2.736 J = 2.7W

if you provide 2.7W to nichrome  for 1 second you won't feel any heat.

**heat ?**

specific heat of nichrome = 455 J/kg.K

eg. 10 gram of nichrome needs around 4.55 J to bring up 1 Celsius of it's  current temperature.

you need to try with lithium battery or acid lead battery  or [supercapacitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercapacitor)

Comment: You Can't charge a capacitor with AC.

Comment: updated. but i not sure when i put my fan capacitor into AC source(220V 50Hz). when capacitor two wires get touch they get sparks. might be they are charged?

Comment: I charger it with 110v ac all the time. Works fine as a small non painful taser

Comment: @editinit How to explode a large-value capacitor:  connect it to AC line voltage, then run away fast.   (But yes, you can use AC to charge a small-value capacitor, well below 1uF, 400V rating.  When it disconnects from AC, it's left with the last voltage that the sine wave delivered.)

Comment: @wbeaty never tried :) . cool but what will happens when AC sine wave at 0V and we removed the capacitor from the power source? will it be charged ?

Comment: @editinit  It will be uncharged.  If you bump the capacitor terminals against AC line voltage, each time it hits you'll get a random phase.  For 120V line volts, the dc volts on the capacitor can be as high as 120*1.414 = 170V, either pos or neg.   But that's right at the peak.  Usually it's less, and sometimes it's very close to zero volts.